# HttpsURLConnection and Volley difference

Tags: java, android, post

I have a problem about sending post data to server and have different result for both of this as mention in title.
with Volley I'm doing this with success
but different result on using HttpsUrlConnection
my parameter post is:

```
String id = "104";
String type = "b";
String curl = "http://127.0.0.1/api/getData?date=today&status=release";
```

building params Map for Volley method:

```
Map<String, String> mapData = new HashMap<>();
mapData.put("id", id);
mapData.put("type", type);
mapData.put("curl", curl);
```

building params for HttpsUrlConnection:

```
String postData="id="+id;
postData +="&type="+type;
postData +="&curl="+curl;
byte[] postDataBytes = postData.getBytes("UTF-8");
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
```

any suggestion how come its like this or maybe I have wrong way to using HttpsUrlConnection, its possible because key "curl" using ampersand?

Comment: server is output as Json, does the output type make diffrerence?
server is already made before for internal use..
and its like wrapping getData method from localhost

Comment: can you pleas add Volley objectrequest method here?

Comment: Are you passing params like JsonObjectRequest jsonObjRequest  = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    API.API.getMethod(),new JSONObject(postParams), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()...

Comment: the problem is in using HttpsUrlConnection...
volley is OK

Comment: error log: org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

seems that server not giving output

Comment: ohh.. that means you res. is coming in String.. and you are fetching string as json so it is not converting in jsonobj.

Comment: response is in JSON... using HttpsUrlConnection get NO Data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117512/discussion-between-sameer-donga-and-ntaloventi).

Comment: possible server cut down `curl` key as " `http://127.0.0.1/api/getData?date=today`

Comment: You don't need to set the content-length, but you do need to write those POST parameters to the output stream, not put them in the URL, and to do that you need to call `setDoOutput(true)`, which sets the request method to POST, which you therefore also don't need to do yourself.

Comment: can you give example.. so I can try...

Comment: `connection.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }`
is this as you taught?